# Formatting a cell containing a date and time with an offset

Tags: excel, datetime, format, cell

How to format Excel cell to force Excel to use it as datetime.
Cell contents: **2023-01-24 23:06:55+01**

I expect something like: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
but how to set timezone offset?
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the numberformat can't calculate. You might need to add a helper column to calculate the new time. That you can format.

[image]

If you want to replace the date text string into a real date you could do like in the picture below. But there are many ways to do it.
Simple formating is not possible you have to remove the offset first. So a helper column is needed for this.

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A5;{"+";"-"};3;;1)+0
```

replace semicolon with comma if your Excel version needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's useful and I'll use it in another situation, but I'm currently looking for something else. I'm trying to clarify: +01 in the record does not mean that one hour needs to be added to obtain the local time, it only informs that the displayed time is shifted by one hour compared to UTC. The datetime before the offset is what I want Excel to use, I just don't know how to format the cell so that it ignores the +01 and looks at the cell contents as a date and time, not as text. For now, I'm just erasing what's behind +

Comment: @viliam I updated the answer, hope I understood you right. From this, you can see the importance to show sample data in the question. "This data I have" and "I wish it look like this" and then show pictures and provide sample data in a table with help of https://www.tablesgenerator.com/